# Why doesn't my code generate in the web browser? XML, DTD, CSS

Tags: css, xml, web, dtd

It begins to print everything up till `29d 18h 46m` and then it stops. idk why. O.o

Can someone tell me why it prints up until that point and then stops?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?DOCTYPE phones SYSTEM "http://userpages.umbc.edu/~v16/is448/hw4/hw4_phones.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://userpages.umbc.edu/~v16/is448/hw4/hw4_phones.css" ?>

<phones>
    <phone>

        <title>Apple iPhone 4S - 16GB - White (Factory Unlocked) Smartphone</title>
        <gBay_id>Item: 160913150440</gBay_id>
        <user_id>Seller: milehighmobilellc</user_id>
        <category>Type: Smartphone</category>
        <condition>Condition: Used</condition>
        <brand>Brand: Apple</brand>
        <model>Model: iPhone 4s</model>
        <carrier>Carrier: Factory Unlocked</carrier>
        <color>Color: White</color>
        <OS>Operating System: Apple iOS</OS>
        <contract>Contract: Without Contract</contract>
        <style>Form Factor: Bar</style>
        <buying_format>Buy It Now</buying_format>
        <auction>
            <starting_price>N/A</starting_price>
            <duration>N/A</duration>
        </auction>
        <buy_it_now>
            <starting_price>$449.99</starting_price>
            <duration>29d 18h 46m</duration>
        </buy_it_now>
        <description>
            Just when you thought a smartphone couldn’t get any better, it just did — the
            iPhone 4S is sure to change the way you communicate. The Siri technology lets
            you talk to this Apple smartphone as you would talk to a person, turning the
            iPhone 4S into a personal assistant. The powerful dual-core A5 chip ensures that
            this Apple phone gives you a lightning-fast performance and life-like graphics.
            Shoot 1080p HD videos and click crystal-clear snaps with the 8 MP camera of this
            Apple smartphone. To make your life easier, this Apple phone runs on iOS 5 that
            lets you enjoy numerous features and an easy-to-use interface. That’s not all;
            with the iCloud feature of the iPhone 4S, you can stop worrying about managing
            your stuff, because your phone does it for you.
        </description>
        <shipping>
        <cost>$0.00</cost>
        <speed>Expedited Shipping</speed>
        <shipping>
        <payment>PayPal, Bill Me Later</payment>
    </phone>

    <phone>

        <title>HTC Droid Incredible - 8GB - Black (Verizon) Smartphone</title>
        <gBay_id>Item: 251173407738</gBay_id>
        <user_id>Seller: jpfredd710</user_id>
        <category>Type: Smartphone</category>
        <condition>Condition: Used</condition>
        <brand>Brand: HTC</brand>
        <model>Model: Droid Incredible</model>
        <carrier>Carrier: Verizon</carrier>
        <color>Color: Black</color>
        <OS>Operating System: Android 2.3.4</OS>
        <contract>Contract: Without Contract</contract>
        <style>Form Factor: Bar</style>
        <buying_format>Auction</buying_format>
        <auction>
            <starting_price price="$62.01"></starting_price>
            <duration time="50m 30s"></duration>
        </auction>
        <buy_it_now>
            <starting_price price="N/A"></starting_price>
            <duration time="N/A"></duration>
        </buy_it_now>
        <description>
            The HTC Droid Incredible lets you communicate effortlessly through its
            touchscreen interface. This HTC smartphone has a 3.7-inch, 480x800-pixels
            resolution AMOLED display. Shoot pictures and videos using the built-in
            8.0-megapixel camera. This HTC cell phone has a 1 GHz Snapdragon processor,
            and 512 MB RAM running Google’s Android 2.1 or 2.3.4 (Gingerbread) with HTC
            Sense UI. What’s more, this CDMA HTC smartphone is Wi-Fi-ready. This HTC
            mobile phone has 8 GB memory, and supports up to 32 GB microSD memory cards.
            The HTC Droid Incredible has built-in Bluetooth 2.1 with A2DP support, and
            a microUSB 2.0 port.
        </description>
        <shipping>
        <cost>$5.99</cost>
        <speed>Economy Shipping</speed>
        <shipping>
        <payment>PayPal, Bill Me Later</payment>
    </phone>

    <phone>

        <title>HTC 7 Pro - 16GB - Gray (U.S. Cellular) Smartphone</title>
        <gBay_id>Item: 181006815999</gBay_id>
        <user_id>Seller: st4mford</user_id>
        <category>Type: Smartphone</category>
        <condition>Condition: Used</condition>
        <brand>Brand: HTC</brand>
        <model>Model: 7 Pro</model>
        <carrier>Carrier: U.S. Cellular</carrier>
        <color>Color: Black</color>
        <OS>Operating System: Windows Phone 7</OS>
        <contract>Contract: Without Contract</contract>
        <style>Form Factor: Bar</style>
        <buying_format>Auction</buying_format>
        <auction>
            <starting_price price="$79.99"></starting_price>
            <duration time="1h 14m 29s"></duration>
        </auction>
        <buy_it_now>
            <starting_price price="$119.99"></starting_price>
            <duration time="1h 14m 29s"></duration>
        </buy_it_now>
        <description>
            View and edit the office docs on your phone. Quickly and easily cut through
            the clutter to see only the unread, urgent, or flagged messages in your
            Outlook inbox. And use SharePoint, when you need a little bit of help from
            your team to crack the project.The slide and tilt screen on the HTC 7 Pro
            angles perfectly to reveal a dedicated QWERTY keyboard. The keys are raised
            and nicely spaced for fast and comfortable typing. And because the screen
            tilts, the HTC 7 Pro is perfect for watching videos - hands free - when you
            have a brief moment to kick back and relax.
        </description>
        <shipping>
        <cost price="$3.99"></cost>
        <speed type="Economy Shipping"></speed>
        <shipping>
        <payment>PayPal, Bill Me Later</payment>
    </phone>
```

Styles:

```css
phones  {   font-family:arial,calibri;  }
title   {   font-size:125%;     font-family:trebuchet ms, arial;    font-style:bold;    }
gBay_id     {   font-size:75%;  color: blue;    }
user_id     {   font-style:bold;    }
buying_format   {   background-color: #D8D8D8;  }
auction     {   background-color: #D8D8D8;  }
buy_it_now  {   background-color: #D8D8D8;  }
```

Comment: I'm having troubles posting the DTD file, so here's a link to it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wq1lyewnz9th07/hw4_phones.dtd

Comment: ok one question, what is this?

Comment: interesting question. The assignment asks to use XML to create a very simple eBay webpage called gBay.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have a few errors.

- You haven't closed your shipping tags correctly.  They should be:

> ```
> <shipping>
>     <cost>$0.00</cost>
>     <speed>Expedited Shipping</speed> 
> </shipping>
> ```

- You missed the final closing tag:

> ```
> </phones>
> ```

- I find chrome to give very useful error messages to help fixing xml errors.  For example before I fixed the closing tag `</phones>`, the error message in chrome showed:

> ```
> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 129 at column 10: Extra content at the end of the document
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
> ```

Comment: Moreover, the start tags `<phones>` and `<phone>` are missing. The code posted can hardly be the code actually used, since browsers would not just print it up to some point; they show syntax errors, instead of displaying the content. The CSS code at the bottom should of course go to an external file, which is just referred to in XML code.

Comment: @Jukka - Actually if you go into edit mode on the original post, you'll see that the tags are there.  They were not visible on SO due to incorrect formatting.  I've made the edits and am awaiting the original poster to approve.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the well-formedness errors already mentioned by manishie, you need to correct the malformed document type declaration:  for

```
<?DOCTYPE ... >
```

read

```
<!DOCTYPE ... >
```

When I fix that as well as the WF errors, the page displays normally and the CSS style appears to be used as one might expect.

With the bad DOCTYPE declaration, the parser identifies  -- thus swallowing your xml-stylesheet instruction.  I have no idea why you were seeing the first part of the document and not the whole document, though.